# If a polytope is centrally symmetric and combinatorially equivalent to a zonotope, is it a zonotope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, zonotopes

A zonotope is a polytope whose 2-faces are centrally symmetric.

> **Question:** If a polytope $P$ is centrally symmetric and combinatorially equivalent to a zonotope, is it itself a zonotope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In retrospect, there are easy counterexamples.

For example, the *truncatd octahedron* (or [permutahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron)) is a zonotope.
However, below (on the right) is a centrally symmetric realization that is not a zonotope (it has non-centrally symmetric faces):

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is one kind of belt polytope that's not a zonotope (an equivalent condition for belt polytopes is that every 2-face has an even number of edges and opposite edges are parallel, see the Ziegler reference I mentioned before).

Answer (score 4):

There are polytopes whose normal fans are central hyperplane arrangements which are not zonotopes. These are called "belt polytopes." I think they would give a counterexample to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A quick google gave not much, but I will look deeper into that. If you have a more concrete example I would be very happy.

Comment: Maybe see Exercise 7.4 of Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes."